# I am trying to append values to an empty 2D array dynamically but getting an error everytime

Tags: numpy, dynamic, append

output = np.empty([17157,4])

## for every row in data

for rows in data:

## initializing variables

```
  snowfall = 0
  positive_temp = 0
  mass_balance = 0
  melt = 0
```

## for every cell in a row

```
  for columns in range(12):

      if rows[columns+2] < 0:

          snowfall += rows[columns+14]

      else:

          positive_temp += rows[columns+2]
          melt += positive_temp * 7

      mass_balance += snowfall - melt

  lat = rows[0] 
  lon = rows[1] 
  elev = rows[26]
```

## appending values to output

```
  np.append(output, ([lat, lon, mass_balance, elev]), axis = 0)
```

Comment: Read np.empty and np.append docs first.

Comment: test small pieces of code.  and small arrays, not something with 17000 rows

Comment: The error must not be important, since you don't tell us anything about it!  or your efforts to understand and correct it.

Comment: In your case, like "getting an error", the very basic details are:
1. What error you get (error message). 2. In which line it occurred.
Don't force us to guess all these details. Please post also a sample of your source data leading to this error (but no more than 20-30 rows) and the expected result.

Comment: I tried initializing empty array in this manner - **_np.empty([0,4], float)_** and tried appending to the output array as - 
**_output = np.append(output, np.array([lat,on,mass_balance,elev]), axis=0)_**
these values are being printed correctly but when I'm trying to store them in **output** array I get dummy values